Proper command for mounting Synology NAS on Ubuntu Linux via terminal
I have a Synology NAS DS223j that I need to access via an Ubuntu PC. Is this the correct way to mount a Synology NAS in Ubuntu Linux in the terminal?
sudo mount -v -t cifs //192.168.0.96/$MOUNTFOLDER /home/tim/trantor/$MOUNTFOLDER -o rw -o user=tim,password=MyPassword,uid=tim,gid=tim

Many thanks

What happens when you run that command?
